# How can I shorten my code? I know there is a way to shorten it but I can't figure it out

Tags: python

I am trying to make a dnd character creator for fun, and I have a lot of it done, but I don't know how to make the repeated code shorter. This is because I don't think I need that much of it.

```
import random

with open("dnd_character.txt", "w") as txt:
```

most of the problem is in the character function.

```
def character():
    player_name = input("enter your first name! ")
    character_name = input("enter your characters name! ")
    print("what race do you want your character to be?\n1. Dwarf\n2. Elf\n3. Halfling\n4. Human\n5. Dragonborn\n6. Gnome\n7. Half-Elf\n8. Half-Orc\n9. Tiefling")
    character_race = input("use the corresponding number to pick: ")
    #there is probably a better way of doing this but I can't figure it out just yet.
    if character_race == "1":
        character_race = "Dwarf"
        race_size = "medium"
        race_size_range = "4-5"
        race_age_max = "350"
        race_age_range = "50-300"
        race_speed = "25"
        race(player_name, character_name, character_race, race_size, race_size_range, race_age_max, race_age_range, race_speed)
    elif character_race == "2":
        character_race = "Elf"
        race_size = "medium"
        race_size_range = "5-6"
        race_age_max = "750"
        race_age_range = "100-750"
        race_speed = "30"
        race(player_name, character_name, character_race, race_size, race_size_range, race_age_max, race_age_range, race_speed)
    elif character_race == "3":
        character_race = "Halfling"
        race_size = "small"
        race_size_range = "2-4"
        race_age_max = "250"
        race_age_range = "20-250"
        race_speed = "25"
        race(player_name, character_name, character_race, race_size, race_size_range, race_age_max, race_age_range, race_speed)
    elif character_race == "4":
        character_race = "Human"
        race_size = "medium"
        race_size_range = "5-6"
        race_age_max = "100"
        race_age_range = "15-100"
        race_speed = "30"
        race(player_name, character_name, character_race, race_size, race_size_range, race_age_max, race_age_range, race_speed)
    elif character_race == "5":
        character_race = "Dragonborn"
        race_size = "medium"
        race_size_range = "6-8"
        race_age_max = "80"
        race_age_range = "10-80"
        race_speed = "30"
        race(player_name, character_name, character_race, race_size, race_size_range, race_age_max, race_age_range, race_speed)
    elif character_race == "6":
        character_race = "Gnome"
        race_size = "small"
        race_size_range = "3-4"
        race_age_max = "500"
        race_age_range = "40-500"
        race_speed = "25"
        race(player_name, character_name, character_race, race_size, race_size_range, race_age_max, race_age_range, race_speed)
    elif character_race == "7":
        character_race = "Half-Elf"
        race_size = "medium"
        race_size_range = "5-6"
        race_age_max = "180"
        race_age_range = "20-180"
        race_speed = "30"
        race(player_name, character_name, character_race, race_size, race_size_range, race_age_max, race_age_range, race_speed)
    elif character_race == "8":
        character_race = "Half-Orc"
        race_size = "medium"
        race_size_range = "5-6"
        race_age_max = "75"
        race_age_range = "10-75"
        race_speed = "30"
        race(player_name, character_name, character_race, race_size, race_size_range, race_age_max, race_age_range, race_speed)
    else:
        character_race = "tiefling"
        race_size = "medium"
        race_size_range = "5-6"
        race_age_max = "100"
        race_age_range = "15-100"
        race_speed = "30"
        race(player_name, character_name, character_race, race_size, race_size_range, race_age_max, race_age_range, race_speed)
    #ugly code over.
```

I wish I knew how to fix this, I left the rest of this for context I guess.

```
def race(player_name, character_name, character_race, race_size, race_size_range, race_age_max, race_age_range, race_speed):
    print(f"{character_race} live around {race_age_max} years. so i would suggest anywhere between {race_age_range}")
    player_age = input("input character age: ")
    print(f"{character_race} sizes are: {race_size_range} feet tall, {race_size}")
    player_height = input("input character height: ")
    player_weight = input("input character weight: ")

    txt.write(f"player name: {player_name}\ncharacter name: {character_name}\nrace: {character_race}\nage: {player_age}\nheight: {player_height}\nweight: {player_weight}\nspeed: {race_speed} feet\n")
    txt.write("consult the book for items, subraces and stuff. i am tired and dont know how to make this better, will make it better later.")

def stat_roll():
    '''this will make a list of stats for the 4d6 rolls, then remove the lowest number, then add them up.'''
    stat_list = []
    for _ in range(4):
        dice1 = (random.randint(1,6))
        stat_list.append(dice1)
    lowestnum = min(stat_list)
    stat_list.remove(lowestnum)
    stat_sum = sum(stat_list)
    txt.write(f"{str(stat_sum)}\n")
character()
#this is to print all of the stats.
txt.write("these are the stats of your character!\n")
for _ in range(6):
    stat_roll()
```

I would like to significantly refactor this code but I have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: One small improvement is to remove all those `race(player_name, character_name, ...)` calls in each if/elif block, and just put one at the end.  They're all identical.

Comment: Questions about code review/improvement are better asked on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Shorter is not always better. Google "obfuscated C contest". Having said that I would use a dictionary of named tuples to hold the character data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focusing on just the "pick a race" part of the code, one way I might suggest shortening it down would be to assemble all those common pieces of information into a `dataclass`, and building a list of all the options:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Race:
    character_race: str
    race_size: str
    race_size_range: str
    race_age_max: str
    race_age_range: str
    race_speed: str

races = [
    Race("Dwarf", "medium", "4-5", "350", "50-300", "25"),
    Race("Elf", "medium", "5-6", "750", "100-750", "30"),
    Race("Halfling", "small", "2-4", "250", "20-250", "25"),
    Race("Human", "medium", "5-6", "100", "15-100", "30"),
    Race("Dragonborn", "medium", "6-8", "80", "10-80", "30"),
    Race("Gnome", "small", "3-4", "500", "40-500", "25"),
    Race("Half-Elf", "medium", "5-6", "180", "20-180", "30"),
    Race("Half-Orc", "medium", "5-6", "75", "10-75", "30"),
    Race("tiefling", "medium", "5-6", "100", "15-100", "30"),
]

def character():
    player_name = input("enter your first name! ")
    character_name = input("enter your characters name! ")
    print("what race do you want your character to be?")
    for i, race in enumerate(races, 1):
        print(f"{i}. {race.character_race}")
    race = races[int(input("use the coresponding number to pick: "))-1]

    print(f"{race.character_race} live around {race.race_age_max} years. so i would suggest anywhere between {race.race_age_range}")
    player_age = input("input character age: ")
    print(f"{race.character_race} sizes are: {race.race_size_range} feet tall, {race.race_size}")
    player_height = input("input character height: ")
    player_weight = input("input character weight: ")

    print(f"player name: {player_name}")
    print(f"character name: {character_name}")
    print(f"race: {race.character_race}")
    print(f"age: {player_age}")
    print(f"height: {player_height}")
    print(f"weight: {player_weight}")
    print(f"speed: {race.race_speed} feet")
    print("consult the book for items, subraces and stuff. "
          "i am tired and dont know how to make this better, will make it better later.")

character()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the data about your character's race in a dictionary.

```
# Dictionary to store race details
races = {
    "1": {
        "name": "Dwarf",
        "size": "medium",
        "size_range": "4-5",
        "age_max": "350",
        "age_range": "50-300",
        "speed": "25",
    },
    "2": {
        "name": "Elf",
        "size": "medium",
        "size_range": "5-6",
        "age_max": "750",
        "age_range": "100-750",
        "speed": "30",
    },
    "3": {
        "name": "Halfling",
        "size": "small",
        "size_range": "2-4",
        "age_max": "250",
        "age_range": "20-250",
        "speed": "25",
    },
    "4": {
        "name": "Human",
        "size": "medium",
        "size_range": "5-6",
        "age_max": "100",
        "age_range": "15-100",
        "speed": "30",
    },
    "5": {
        "name": "Dragonborn",
        "size": "medium",
        "size_range": "6-8",
        "age_max": "80",
        "age_range": "10-80",
        "speed": "30",
    },
    "6": {
        "name": "Gnome",
        "size": "small",
        "size_range": "3-4",
        "age_max": "500",
        "age_range": "40-500",
        "speed": "25",
    },
    "7": {
        "name": "Half-Elf",
        "size": "medium",
        "size_range": "5-6",
        "age_max": "180",
        "age_range": "20-180",
        "speed": "30",
    },
    "8": {
        "name": "Half-Orc",
        "size": "medium",
        "size_range": "5-6",
        "age_max": "75",
        "age_range": "10-75",
        "speed": "30",
    },
}
```

And the rest of the code could look like this:

```
def race_selection():
    print("What race do you want your character to be?")
    for key, race in races.items():
        print(f"{key}. {race['name']}")
    character_race = input("Use the corresponding number to pick: ")
    return races.get(character_race)

def character():
    player_name = input("Enter your first name! ")
    character_name = input("Enter your character's name! ")
    race_details = race_selection()
    # Handle invalid input or default to Tiefling
    if not race_details:
        race_details = races["9"]

    character_race = race_details["name"]
    race_size = race_details["size"]
    race_size_range = race_details["size_range"]
    race_age_max = race_details["age_max"]
    race_age_range = race_details["age_range"]
    race_speed = race_details["speed"]

    print(f"{character_race} live around {race_age_max} years, so I would suggest anywhere between {race_age_range}")
    player_age = input("Input character age: ")
    print(f"{character_race} sizes are: {race_size_range} feet tall, {race_size}")
    player_height = input("Input character height: ")
    player_weight = input("Input character weight: ")

    txt.write(
        f"player name: {player_name}\ncharacter name: {character_name}\nrace: {character_race}\nage: {player_age}\nheight: {player_height}\nweight: {player_weight}\nspeed: {race_speed} feet\n"
    )
    txt.write("Consult the book for items, subraces, and stuff. I am tired and don't know how to make this better, will make it better later.")

def stat_roll():
    '''This will make a list of stats for the 4d6 rolls, then remove the lowest number, then add them up.'''
    stat_list = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(4)]
    lowest_num = min(stat_list)
    stat_list.remove(lowest_num)
    stat_sum = sum(stat_list)
    txt.write(f"{str(stat_sum)}\n")

# Main program
with open("dnd_character.txt", "w") as txt:
    character()
    # This is to print all of the stats.
    txt.write("These are the stats of your character!\n")
    for _ in range(6):
        stat_roll()
```

Hope this helps!